# Android Retrofit - Wait for response before executing other code?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to return a response from an api. The data from that response is to be supplied to a recyclerview. I get a Null pointer exception on the data object when passing it to the recycler view. This is because, the app does not wait for the response to be returned before setting up the recyclerview. Is there anyway to have the app wait for the response before proceeding?

I've tried making a synchronous retrofit request but I still get the same issue. I've tried calling setupRecyclerView() in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask but this also does not work.

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends BaseActivity {

    // UI
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private SearchView searchbox;
    private RecyclerView rvResults;
    // Business Logic
    private String searchQuery;
    public Response response;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        searchQuery = getSearchQuery();
        setupToolbar(searchQuery);
        searchForProduct(searchQuery);
    }


    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        rvResults = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvResults);
        rvResults.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvResults.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activityContext));
        ResultAdapter adapter = new ResultAdapter(response.getResults());
        rvResults.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setupToolbar(String query) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    }

    private void searchForProduct(String query) {
        new SearchZaposTask().execute("e");
    }

    private String getSearchQuery() {
        String query = "";
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
        return query;
    }

    public class SearchZaposTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response> {

        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(String... params) {

            RestAdapter retrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .build();

            ZapposAPI api = retrofit.create(ZapposAPI.class);
            return api.searchZappos(searchQuery);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response searchresponse) {
            super.onPostExecute(searchresponse);
            //Toast.makeText(activityContext,response.getResults().get(0).getProductName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            response = searchresponse;
            setupRecyclerView();
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: Adding ZapposAPI for @tmalseed to look at

```
public interface ZapposAPI {

    @GET("/mobileapi/v1/search?")
    Response searchZappos(@Query("term") String query);

    @GET("/mobileapi/v1/search?")
    void searchZapos(@Query("term") String query, Callback<Response> responseCallback);

    @GET("https://zappos.amazon.com/mobileapi/v1/product/asin/{asin}")
    Asin searchByAsin(@Path("asin") String asin);
}
```

Comment: For some strange reasons, call to setupRecyclerView won't work. I had similar issue, while if I  call this from onBacakGround() same function call works fine. More insight needed from experts on this issue ! I switched to volley and the i did not face this issue there ! Perhaps you want to give a shot to volley, if it suits your needs !

Comment: You can use Retrofit without asynctask. It could be more easier task. Follow my github repo: https://github.com/manishandroid/RetrofitAndroidExample

Comment: Can you please post your ZapposAPI code?

Comment: @k2ibegin there's no reason why you need to use Volley instead of Retrofit. There is just an issue with the code here.

Marshmallow, that's not a great response. There's no reason why you can't use an AsyncTask to execute a RetroFit http request.

Comment: @k2ibegin I tried adding setupRecyclerView() to the doInBackround method in the AsyncTask but it did not work. I get the same problem where the app doesn't wait for the response to return before executing the next method.

Comment: @tmalseed  : Added ZapposAPI code. Please take a look

Comment: i suggest you put a debugger if you are using android studio and check the flow. Perhaps it should let you figure out why the method is not getting invoked,

Answer (score 0):

Rather do it like this:

```
zapposApi.getWhatever(new Callback<List<YourPOJO>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<YourPOJO> YourPOJO, Response response) {
                setupRecyclerView(YourPOJO);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                //handle your error
            }
        });
```

Your api will have an interface that might look like something in the line of :

```
@GET("/user/current")
    void getCurrentUser(Callback<YourPOJO> response);
```

This way the actual network call is done in the background and the callback is on the UI thread. You don't have to use async for this!.

Comment: I tried this with no luck. I get the following error:                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onAddFocusables(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView, java.util.ArrayList, int, int)' on a null object reference                                                                                    Again I get a null pointer exception on the ArrayList that is supposed to represent my data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. In my original code I wanted to wait until I recieved an api response before setting up the recyclerView. However, Android doesn't like when you delay setting up the recyclerView for too long so I got this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onAddFocusables(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,
>   java.util.ArrayList, int, int)' on a null object reference

This brought me back to the dilemna where I didn't have the response data to setup the recyclerview yet. So in setupRecyclerView(), I imported recyclerview from the xml and setup the layout manager but removed the code that created the adapter and added it to the recyclerview. Then I put the adapter creation code in the success() method of my Callback implementation. This fixed the problem!

Found my solution here: [Why my android activity is crashing with "No adapter attached; skipping layout" but sporadically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276294/why-my-android-activity-is-crashing-with-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

and the code is below.

public class SearchResultsActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
    // UI
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private SearchView searchbox;
    private RecyclerView rvResults;

    // Business Logic
    private String searchQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);
        searchQuery = getSearchQuery();
        setupToolbar();
        setupRecyclerView();
        searchForProducts(searchQuery);
    }

    private void setupToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        rvResults = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvResults);
        rvResults.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rvResults.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activityContext));
    }

    private String getSearchQuery() {
        String query = "";
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        }
        return query;
    }

    private void searchForProducts(String query) {

        RestAdapter retrofit = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .build();

        ZapposAPI api = retrofit.create(ZapposAPI.class);

        api.searchZappos(query, new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Response apiResponse, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                ResultAdapter adapter = new ResultAdapter(apiResponse.getResults());
                rvResults.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. But I have two calls nested. First call is to get the ids of top stories from hackernews. Then loop through the ids and get the item information and display it in the recylerview. I tried your solution but still not updating the view in UI.