# Recyclerview not showing any data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am not getting the data in recyclerview fetch data from server using retrofit client. And not show any value in "Log.d(TAG,"Number of hourly weather data received "+list.size());"

Recyclerview adapter

```
public class HourlyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HourlyAdapter.HourlyViewHolder> {

    List<HourlyList> hourlist;
    Context context;
    public HourlyAdapter(List<HourlyList> hourlist,Context context){
        this.hourlist = hourlist;
        this.context = context;

    }
    @Override
    public HourlyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hourly_list,parent,false);

        return new HourlyViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HourlyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Date date = new Date(hourlist.get(position).getDt()*1000L);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String formateDate = sdf.format(date);
        holder.hour.setText(formateDate);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("datasize", String.valueOf(hourlist.size()));
        return  hourlist == null ? 0 : hourlist.size();

    }

    public class HourlyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.hour)
        TextView hour;
        public HourlyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment file

```
public class HourlyFragment extends Fragment {
   @BindView(R.id.recyclerview)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<HourlyList> list;
    HourlyAdapter adapter;


    public HourlyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false);

         ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);

        adapter = new HourlyAdapter(list,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        hourlyWeather();


        return view;
    }
    public void hourlyWeather(){
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<HourlyWeather> call = apiInterface.getHourlyWeather("London","metric",getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));

        call.enqueue(new Callback<HourlyWeather>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HourlyWeather> call, Response<HourlyWeather> response) {

                    list = response.body().getList();


                Log.d(TAG,"Number of hourly weather data received "+list.size());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);







            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<HourlyWeather> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

interface file

```
@GET("forecast?")
    Call<HourlyWeather> getHourlyWeather(@Query("q") String city,
                                         @Query("units") String units,
                                         @Query("APPID") String appId);
```

retrofit client

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit =null;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit(){
        if (retrofit == null){

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.prem.weatherapp.fragment.HourlyFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>





</RelativeLayout>
```

list of data xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:contentPadding="0dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/date"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hour"
            android:layout_below="@id/date"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: did you check the stacktrace for errors?

Comment: can you share your response structure?

Comment: list = response.body().getList(); -> You're updating reference to list in HourlyFragment not in adapter.

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: possible duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473297/android-retrofit-wait-for-response-before-executing-other-code

Answer (score 1):

This issue is that you set your adapter before you populate your list. You create your adapter before you get a response from your list. You have to remember that when you make your retrofit request, you have to wait for the response. Otherwise, you are just sending an empty list to your adapter.

You should do something more like this:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hourly, container, false);

         ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
        hourlyWeather();


        return view;
    }

 public void hourlyWeather(){
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<HourlyWeather> call = apiInterface.getHourlyWeather("London","metric",getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));

        call.enqueue(new Callback<HourlyWeather>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<HourlyWeather> call, Response<HourlyWeather> response) {

                    list = response.body().getList();

                adapter = new HourlyAdapter(list,getActivity().getApplicationContext());

                Log.d(TAG,"Number of hourly weather data received "+list.size());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);







            }
```

Comment: You should check your `list` then. I'm guessing that the response you're getting isn't the one you expect, or you're `getList()` method isn't returning your list.

Comment: Been looking for a solution for 3 hours now. I finally followed your suggestion moved my code around so that the list is populated before the adapter is created. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create a callback interface

```
public interface callbackInterface {
      public void onSuccess(yourList);
}
```

Then

```
hourlyWeather(new callbackInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(yourList) {
               //Set your adapter here.
       }
}
```

In hourlyWeatherMethod

```
hourlyWeather(callbackInterface ci) {
    //Your retrofit Code goes here
    ci.onSuccess(yourList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest handling Retrofit network call with Android's `LoaderManager` & `AsyncTaskLoader`, not calling it from `onCreateView`.
Feel free to try this approach:

1) Change `HourlyFragment`

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;

public class HourlyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<HourlyList>> {
    final List<HourlyList> list = new ArrayList<>();
    HourlyAdapter adapter;
    .....

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ......

        adapter = new HourlyAdapter(this.list, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<HourlyList>> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        return new HourlyWeatherLoader(this.getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<HourlyList>> arg0, List<HourlyList> datas) {      
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(datas);

        // this shall update recyclerview to show newly added data
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<HourlyList>> arg0) {
    }
```

2) Add new `HourlyWeatherLoader` class to handle Retrofit network call

```
public class HourlyWeatherLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<HourlyList>> {
    private List<HourlyList> list;

    public HourlyWeatherLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<HourlyList> loadInBackground() {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofit().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<HourlyWeather> call = apiInterface.getHourlyWeather("London","metric",getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));

        try {
            HourlyWeather hourlyWeather = call.execute().body();
            this.list = hourlyWeather.getList();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception catched
            .....
        }

        return this.list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(List<HourlyList> list) {
        super.onCanceled(list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (this.list != null) {
            deliverResult(this.list);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || this.list == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();
        onStopLoading();
        this.list = null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!